# Software for checking memory leakage in exe file

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, memory, memory-management

I have an application written in VC++ Windows form applications that interacts with various hardware such as A/D cards, GPIB, D/A etc. My customer ran the application on-site,  and found that the application is crashing after few seconds. I asked him to monitor memory growth through task manager, and I found that indeed , the memory was growing. So it looks like some problem of memory leakage. Now I want to find where exactly in my code , I am not correctly freeing/allocating memory., but I do not have the access to the onsite PC. I have to do this on my PC which is not having those hardware A/D etc.   Is there any software that can accept my exe, and point out the name of functions/code line which is causing the problem, without actually ecxuting my exe?
        My exe would not run since I do not have those hardware.

Comment: You could use a memory profiling tool like Dr. Memory (drmemory.org) - make sure your application is compiled 32-bit with debugging symbols. See here: http://drmemory.org/docs/page_prep.html

Comment: It's off topic to request software/tool/library recommendations on S.O..  That said, the best approach I can think of is finding some static analysis tools, e.g. [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/), and you'd be pretty lucky if they found the bug.  You might try to eliminate most uses of `new` and `delete` by using RAII, e.g. `std::string`, `std::vector`, smart pointers....  Of course you could provide tools or builds for the client to run on site, but I'm assuming you're trying to avoid inconveniencing them further.

Answer (score 0):

I used Smartbear QATime for this tasks. It is a profiler which can also profile heap allocations. In the report, you can get a list of objects which are still alive and also the line where they have been created.